# Unable to add .fetch() returned data to react useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code.

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

const submitLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('password_confirmation', passwordconf);

    setErrors([])

    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST + '/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })

    if (res.status == 422) {
        const terrors = await res.json();
        await setErrors(terrors)
        console.log(terrors);
        console.log(errors);
    }
}
```

even though I'm getting **res.json()** as array I **can't assign them to useState()**.

This is an image of console.log

[image]

Comment: `useState` isn't async so you can't wait for the update, try removing it.

Comment: I think this is working fine, you need to console error state outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState is asynchronous. use useEffect to see the updates to state variable

```
useEffect(() => {       
  console.log(errors);
}, [errors])
```

Also, avoid using await in the setState

```
setErrors(terrors)
```